# SAS: Logic to subtract two numbers on FIFO basis

Tags: sas, proc, step

I have a problem which I need to implement using SAS PSQL. I have thought of implementing it using macros.

I will try to break my problem down into phases. For the first phase I am struck on how do I iterate over rows accessing each cell values doing some manipulations and calculations on those values. An example is:

For a client "A" a financial institution buys USD 100, USD 400, USD 500 and then for the same client "A" it sells USD 350. Now beginning with USD 350 (considering it was on xx date). My calculation would be:

USD350 - USD 100 = USD 250 (It is not zero so we proceed to next step)
USD 250 - USD 400 = -150 USD (<0 so we stop here and log this value along with date and then calculate aging by subtracting the start date of sale and date of this purchase).

So I am guessing that I have to iterate over values and I am currently unable to do so. Can someone guide me to a sample of iteration (For loop)?

**Edit**
We are doing this exercise at month end to calculate total unutilized stock  .Hence on FIFO (First IN First OUT )basis, first sell amount should get minus with first buy amount based on buy_date for a client . Any residual amount of first buy is to be carried forward for the calculation of next sell transaction (based on buy date).code is given below .but problem is BUY of 1-MAR-2018 i.e 100000 is not getting exhausted by sell amount of 50000 of 18-MAR-2018 and 19-MAR-2018.rather it is moving on next buy amount which is 50000 of 02-mar-2018.
data want;

```
set sample_2;    
by SECURITY_ID;    
array d{99999} _temporary_;    
array t{99999} _temporary_;    
retain count;

if first.SECUIRTY_ID then do;k=-0;SELL=0;BUY=0;count=0;call missing(of d{*} t{*});end;

if B_S='buy' then do;    
  k+1;    
  d{k}=buy_date;    
  t{k}=stock;    
end;    

if B_S='sell' then do;    
  SELL+stock;FIFO=d{ifn(count=0,1,count)};    
  do i=count+1 to k;    
   BUY+t{i};    
   if SELL lt BUY then do;count=i;leave;end;    
  end;    
end;    

format FIFO date11.;    
REM_QTY = SELL - BUY;    
drop BUY SELL i k count REM_QTY;    
run;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have a few issues with this question - don't use all caps for text, it's the internet equivalent of yelling at people. Additionally, its not clear for your logic of how to go from one input to another. I would suggest editing your question to simplify it to a single issue and explicitly showing, what you have, what you want, the logic to get there and what you've tried. Then you'll get a response fairly quickly.

Comment: Do you really mean to match them or just process them in order?  Do you have more than one transaction per day?  If yes how do you want to order within the day. How is this different than calculating a running total where BUY means add and SELL means subtract?

Comment: What I meant was: If I have for example 4 buys for a client "A" - USD 100,200,300,400 and 1 sale USD 350. Now my logic should keep calculating the difference between buy and sale until I get 0 or buys are finished (For that particular client). And I have to minus the sale from purchase on a first in first out basis. 350-100 = 200 then 200-200 = 0 (Stop). My main problem is how do I iterate on rows to perform these calculations.

Comment: Why would you use SQL?  Just use a data step. That will process the observations in order.

Comment: If the buys and sells are from the same client why does it matter?  Is the goal to match buyers to sellers?  Or perhaps to find the proper basis value for sells?

Comment: Goal is to find balance of sales and buys for a client but in fifo order. Sales - buy - buy - buy (until balance is 0)

Comment: What if the order was Buy - Sell - Sell - Buy - Sell ?  That seems a reasonable possibility.  Is it that you want to flag every time the total hits zero?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really explained what you want.  If you want to process records in order then use normal DATA step.

Let's make some sample data.

```
data have ;
 length client $5 date 8 type $4 amount 8 ;
 input client date type amount ;
 informat date yymmdd.;
 format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
A 2018-03-01 BUY 100
A 2018-03-02 BUY 400
A 2018-03-03 SELL 350
A 2018-03-04 BUY 500
;
```

Now let's process in each client in order.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by client date ;
  if first.client then on_hand =0;
  if type='BUY' then on_hand+amount;
  if type='SELL' then on_hand+-amount;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    client          date    type    amount    on_hand

 1       A       2018-03-01    BUY       100       100
 2       A       2018-03-02    BUY       400       500
 3       A       2018-03-03    SELL      350       150
 4       A       2018-03-04    BUY       500       650
```

Comment: Please check the answer below. I was unable to post an image here in comments so I had to post it as answer